# multiple subplots on same figure with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Hi so I have a function that plots timeseries data for a given argument (in my case its a country name). Now some of the columns have na values and when i try to plot them I cant because of thos NaN values. How can I solve this problem?
This is the code, which gets you dataframe and function im using:

```
url2='https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=phAwcNAVuyj1jiMAkmq1iMg&output=xls'
source=io.BytesIO(requests.get(url2).content)
income=pd.read_excel(source)
income.head()
income.set_index("GDP per capita", inplace=True)
def gdpchange(country):
    dfff=income.loc[country]
    dfff.T.plot(kind='line')
    plt.legend([country])
```

Now if I want to plot all of them on one graph it gives an error because of nan values in some columns. Any suggestions?

```
for ctr in income.index.values:
    gdpchange(ctr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to drop all `nan` values with `pandas.dropna()`:

```
income.dropna(inplace=True)
```

This statement drops all rows that have any `nan` values in `income` dataframe.

Comment: Ah well yes in this case it works, because whole rows has NaN values, but what if there are NaN values in some of the columns in given row?

Comment: Read the manual http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html You have two values of `how` argument: "all" (drop only rows where all values are `nan`) or "any" (drop rows where any of values are `nan`). The code below works in "any" mode.